# How to get group object through csom?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, groups

my scenario : i tried the GetGroupByName method but didnt work,it cant find the group, i am not able to find the id of the group also.

```
 GroupCollection groupColl = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
                Group newgroup = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("InternalUsers");
                clientContext.Load(groupColl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: can you please share the code that you have tried ?

Comment: @GautamSheth i edited the question

Comment: I think you need to change it to `clientContext.Load(newgroup);`. Also ensure that you are passing the correct group name.

Comment: @GautamSheth didnt work,note that this group was created on azure,am being told it a domain group

Comment: its needs to be a sharepoint group.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code below :

```
GroupCollection groupColl = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups;
Group newgroup = groupColl.GetByName("InternalUsers");
clientContext.Load(newgroup);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: didnt work, i am being told the group is a domain group

Comment: The above code actually works for SharePoint Groups.  Domain groups are treated differently and you'd have to crack open your domain group using Active Directory APIs.  Per the error message, the Group name you used is NOT a SharePoint group, but an AD group.  As such, SharePoint cannot return anything because even if it had the AD group object, it would be a type mismatch when returned since GetByName() is expected to return a SharePoint Group.